# Program to shoot SCSI Reservations & Release towards EMC Clariion (On Linux)

Tags: c, linux, scsi, emc

I am trying to write a program to shoot SCSI Reservations & Release towards EMC Clariion (On Linux), I have done the same on solaris with Sun StoreEdge using the mhd library in solaris but unable to find such interface in linux with EMC. My program will be used by our in house cluster that would us Storage as a "Non-shared multihost disk". Please suggest me some documentation or template program over the same. Thanks in advance for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [sg_utils](http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sg3_utils.html). I am not sure whether it will server your purpose.